# What is wrong with the result of the quantity of each item in my code?

Tags: java

for my code I need to display the quantities of the items entered, for example if banana, Banana, yogurt was entered, the total would be 3 and banana x2, yogurt x1
I'm struggling with the output. I'm aware there's an easier way to do this w HashMap, but I don't want to use it since I haven't learned about it.
Okay I put the counter inside the loop but say if I inputted rice, RICE, RIce, MANY RICE, I would want my output to be rice x3, MANY RICE x1 but instead I got rice x2 RIce x2?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("Enter want you want to purchase:");
    Scanner read= new Scanner(System.in);
    String item  = read.nextLine();

    while(!item.equals("stop")) {
        list.add(item);
        item = read.nextLine();
}
System.out.println("Total items: " +list.size());

    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
     int count = 0;
        System.out.print(list.get(i) + "x");
    for(int j=0; j<list.size(); j++){
        if(list.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(j)))
            count++;
        if(list.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(j)) && count>1)
            list.remove(j);   
    }                    
        System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Which is your current output?

Comment: `list.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(j))` will always be true at least once in each loop

Comment: Let's say your list contains `A, B, C, D, E` and `j` is 2 (points to `C`). If you then call `remove(j)` you have `A, B, D, E`, and you then continue loop, so `j++` sets `j` to 3 (points to `E`). **OOPS!** *You just skipped `D`.*

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to reset your counter variable `count` to 0 when counting the occurences of a new element:

```
...
System.out.println("Total items: " + list.size());

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int count = 0; // Initialize the count variable here
    ...
```

(Makes sense, because you're only setting `count` to 0 once, which means it will only keep incrementing...)